# How to transfer some variable to django form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I want to make a custom form field validation to check if entered string is an email of `user` variable. Smth like this:

```
class FullEmailOrPhoneForm(forms.Form):
    entered_string = forms.CharField()

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('entered_string',)

def clean_entered_string(self):

    email = self.cleaned_data['entered_string']
    if email == user.email: # I need user variable for this comprasion
        ans = email
    else:
        raise ValidationError('Incorrect email')
    return ans
```

My view:

```
def reset_password_with_username(request, user):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FullEmailOrPhoneForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pass
    else:
        form = FullEmailOrPhoneForm()
return render(request, 'registration/password_reset_with_username.html')
```

So how can I transfer `user` variable from view to form validation function?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `__init__()` method of your form so it can receive an extra argument, the `user`:

```
# inside FullEmailOrPhoneForm 
def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = user  # now you can use self.user anywhere in your form
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def clean_entered_string(self):
    ...
    if self.user and email == self.user.email:
        ...

# inside your view you have to specify `data=` since the first init arg is now the user.
form = FullEmailOrPhoneForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
# or with no data
form = FullEmailOrPhoneForm(user=request.user)
```

Note that you created a `Form`, not a `ModelForm`, so your `Meta` class is completely useless. If in fact, you wanted to have a `ModelForm` that models the user being edited (and the `user` you want to pass to the form is the same `user` as the one being edited), you should do this using the `instance` of the form:

```
class FullEmailOrPhoneForm(forms.ModelForm):  # <-- note the ModelForm here
    ...    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ...

    def clean_entered_string(self):
        ...
        if self.instance and email == self.instance.email:
            ...

# then in your view:
form = FullEmailOrPhoneForm(request.POST, instance=user)
```